# Differences in reading file using ifstream in g++ and msvc

Tags: c++, stream, filestream, std, ifstream

When using ifstream class to read words from an input file, I have used the following expression:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   std::ifstream inputStream(myFile.txt);
   std::string myString;
   myFile.open()
   while(myFile.good())
   {
      myFile >> myString;
      printf("%s \n", myString);
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

The contents of myFile.txt are:
" This is a simple program. "

The compiles and executes as expected using g++ compiler.

However, the same code when compiled using msvc 2008, returns error at the extraction operator (>>) requiring me to replace the std::string with either an initialized character array or any of the supported native types.
This threw me off as I was expecting the usage of the standard library to be same across implementations.
I understand the compile error and know the way to fix it via using c_str().

But, it would help me a great deal, if someone could clarify why the usage for the standard library is different across platforms.
 To me it is not starndard anymore !!

EDIT: Code updated to be complete. Content of myFile.txt updated.

Comment: What is `myFile`? You haven't defined one. If ot is `inputStream`, latter has no `open` without arguments.

Comment: @Lol4t0 Code updated to be complete. Also, the mode is ios_base::in by default. Reference at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/open/

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Make than the answer, I've been bitten by this before

Comment: @JerryCoffin Your fix works. Need to include #include <string> in the header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are that you forgot to `#include <string>`. Without it, Microsoft's version of `<iostream>` (and such) include enough of a declaration of `std::string` for some things to work, but other parts are missing, so you get strange, seemingly inexplicable failures.

One of the things that's missing is most of the operator overloads for `std::string`, which is exactly what you seem to be missing.

As an aside, `while (myfile.good()) ...` is pretty much a guaranteed bug -- you probably want:

```
while (myfile>>myString)
    std::cout << myString << " \n";
```

Alternatively, you could do the job with a standard algorithm:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::ifstream myfile("input.txt");

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(myfile),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " \n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles fine for me on MSVC 2010:

```
std::ifstream inputStream;
std::string myString;
inputStream.open("myFile.txt", std::ifstream::in);

while(inputStream.good())
{
    inputStream >> myString;
}
```

**Note**: without using `std::ifstream::in` as my open mode, I got the same error as you. I suggest you check what value you have for this parameter.

Comment: I am sure that clip does NOT compile as you can't have statements at filescope (only declarations). Both you and @Vinshnu are not providing all the relevant code.

Comment: @Saul The open method defaults to ios_base::in. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/open/

Comment: @LokiAstari This was in the main() function, sorry for the confusion